Как добавить имя приложения в Dynamic Island в iOS при скриншоте?
Пытаюсь понять как добавить имя своего приложения в Dynamic Island при скриншоте как в телеграм и не понимаю как это сделать. В интернете искал инфу но не получилось найти. Помогите, пожалуйста, ссылкой или примером кода как добавить в Dynamic Island имя приложения при скриншоте.

